# How to drop datetime.time and convert it?

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have a dataset containing 20000 rows and 132 columns, but when handling the data, I had a problem.
When I do .dtype in one of the columns (expected discharge date), it gives me "dtype('O')", however, when I search for some rows in particular, it appears:

```
df['expected discharge date'][58]
datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 24, 0, 0)
```

However in some other rows, it appears:

```
df['expected discharge date'][18]    
datetime.time(0, 0)
```

So, I want to drop all the rows that have "datetime.time", be able to convert this columns to date dtype and just have like this: 
datetime.date(2017, 10, 24)

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.apply()` to test rows for a specific type:

```
import datetime

time_only = df['expected discharge date'].apply(lambda v: isinstance(v, datetime.time))
```

You can then delete the rows masked by `time_only`:

```
del df[time_only]
```

You can combine this into a single statement:

```
del df[df['expected discharge date'].apply(lambda v: isinstance(v, datetime.time))]
```